# appharbor not deploying static files

Tags: appharbor

I have some fonts and other static file that app harbor is not deploying. I can tell it is not deploying because when I go to my site and look at the network tab in dev tools it shows a 404 for the font requests.

I know they are being copied over because in the app harbor build output file it states that

```
  Copying file from "D:\temp\2a4lm22o.yq0\input\foo.Web\foo.Mobile\Content\fonts\flat-ui-icons-regular.svg" to "D:\temp\2a4lm22o.yq0\output\Content\fonts\flat-ui-icons-regular.svg".
         Copying file from "D:\temp\2a4lm22o.yq0\input\foo.Web\foo.Mobile\Content\fonts\flat-ui-icons-regular.eot" to "D:\temp\2a4lm22o.yq0\output\Content\fonts\flat-ui-icons-regular.eot".
         Copying file from "D:\temp\2a4lm22o.yq0\input\foo.Web\foo.Mobile\Content\fonts\flat-ui-icons-regular.ttf" to "D:\temp\2a4lm22o.yq0\output\Content\fonts\flat-ui-icons-regular.ttf".
         Copying file from "D:\temp\2a4lm22o.yq0\input\foo.Web\foo.Mobile\Content\fonts\flat-ui-icons-regular.woff" to "D:\temp\2a4lm22o.yq0\output\Content\fonts\flat-ui-icons-regular.woff"
```

for these fonts I also have set the `build action` to `content` and the `copy to output directory` to `copy always`, but still nothing.

any help would be appreciated in troubleshooting the issue would be appreciated. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldnt get appharbor to recoginize the fonts, so i just uploaded them to AMAZON S3 and referenced them from my scripts.